# How to find all points in a given 3D shape

Tags: integer, geometry, equation, solution

Consider a 3D space, we only study integer points [image: defp]. And then we are given 3  basis vectors (non-orthogonal, of cause) [image: ABC] by which we can obtain a 3D crooked cubic (how to call that in English?). The question is: how to find out all the points inside this crooked cubic? I want to find a way to scan all points near the target space. But I don't know how.

Recently I have some idea to approach to the solution. The solution point [image: b] must satisfy a equation that [image: b=abc] where [image]) for i=1,2,3 (x_i can=0 is my other consideration, that's fine). So the problem is concluded to find the solution of
[image] where A and b are all integer matrix and the first row of [image] is [image], the second row ...

Then I have no ideal what to do next. A super naive solution is to choose a very large space B, and check each point b in B to see if there is a x to satisfy Ax=b.

Is there a better way?

Comment: So you mean, you want to find all the integer points in the parallelepiped (that's the name, BTW) which has one vertex at the origin and arms defined by a1,a2,a3?

Comment: this sounds like **rasterization** in **3D Voxel space** to me (even if the used matrix is non orthogonal) by crooked cubic I hope you mean skeved cube (cubics implies cubic curvatures). The simplest way is to compute BBOX and just test all integer points inside with point inside mesh test. As your mesh is just few planes its not that complicated just 6 `dot` products and one `if`. If you need more speed use scan line algorithms like [3D triangle rasterization into voxel grid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74251621/2521214) just "render" the whole mesh instead of just surface ...

Comment: You might do this also by ray casting see [Drawing 3D sphere in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25135125/2521214)

Comment: @Sneftel exactly right.

Answer (score 0):

A basis like {a1,a2,a3} do not define a parallepiped, but the full 3D space. It's just a different "coordinates-system" from typical orthogonal system.

Any point P(px,py,pz) can be expressed as a combination of base-vectors:

```
P= u1·a1 + u2·a2 + u3·a3
```

This vector equation is expressed in matrix form `[P]=[A]·[u]` by expanding each  vector to its x,y,z components. `[u]` is a column matrix.

To find the [ui] vector for point `Pi` you must invert (i.e. get [A<sup>-1</sup>]) the matrix [A], and then **[ui]=[A<sup>-1</sup>]·[Pi]**

The thing is that we can consider a point to be "inside" the axis if all of `u1,u2,u3` are >= 0

So, to check your collection of points (coords given in cartesian system) you calculate the [ui] componentes for each point `Pi` and check if some component is **< 0**.

Note:

 If all ux,uy,uz belong to [0,1] range it means that `P` is inside a parallepiped (6 faces, edges parallel to axis) whose vertices are defined by start (0,0,0)  and end (aix,aiy,aiz) points.

Don't confuse with "*normalized length*" (Length=1): If all a1,a2,a3 vector have length=1 then you have a "unitary basis"